# How to sort array of structs by descending order in C

Tags: c, function, sorting, struct, qsort

These are my structures:

```
struct create{
    char names[30];
    int Win;
    int Lose;
    int Draw;
    int Points;
    int Average;
    int Goals;
};
```

So, I was searching for a method on how to sort them, by descending order. Like, according to `int Win` if Win is higher than other than it should be at the top.

For ex:

```
Name - Win - Lose - Draw ...
Joe  -  2  -   0  -  0 ...
Bill -  1  -   0  -  1 ...
Mike -  0  -   1  -  1 ...
```

Is it possible? Can someone help me with this.

Comment: `man qsort` ...

Comment: @user9414 It seems you mean to sort in the descending order.:)

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you searched but didn't find any existing resources on how to sort in C.

Comment: @underscore_d I found some, but most of it was for 2 structures and couldn't understand how to do it with more of them.

Comment: Sort functions take 2 objects because they must compare a pair of elements at a time. That is all that's needed to compare and extends naturally to arrays of more than 2 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard C function `qsort` declared in the header `<stdlib.h>` creating an appropriate comparison function.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct create{
    char names[30];
    int Win;
    int Lose;
    int Draw;
    int Points;
    int Average;
    int Goals;
};

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const struct create *left  = a;
    const struct create *right = b;

    return ( left->Win < right->Win ) - ( right->Win < left->Win );  
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct create a[] =
    {
        { .names = "Mike", .Win = 0, .Lose = 1, .Draw = 1 },
        { .names = "Joe",  .Win = 2, .Lose = 0, .Draw = 0 },
        { .names = "Bill", .Win = 1, .Lose = 0, .Draw = 1 },
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%-4s %d %d %d\n", a[i].names, a[i].Win, a[i].Lose, a[i].Draw );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( a, N, sizeof( struct create ), cmp );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%-4s %d %d %d\n", a[i].names, a[i].Win, a[i].Lose, a[i].Draw );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Mike 0 1 1
Joe  2 0 0
Bill 1 0 1

Joe  2 0 0
Bill 1 0 1
Mike 0 1 1
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add to return something like `return ( left->Win < right->Win && left->Draw < right->Draw ) - ( right->Win < left->Win && right->Draw < left->Draw ); `  to add second condition, like if Wins are equal its going to look for Draws as well

Answer (score -1):

A typical sort looks something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct create {
        char name[30];
        int Win;
};

int
comp(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
        const struct create *a = va;
        const struct create *b = vb;
        return a->Win > b->Win ? 1 : b->Win > a->Win ? -1 : 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
        struct create ar[] = {
                { .name = "a", .Win = 5 },
                { .name = "b", .Win = 7 },
                { .name = "c", .Win = 3 },
                { .name = "d", .Win = -1 },
                { .name = "e", .Win = 5 },
                { .name = "f", .Win = 8 }
        };
        qsort(ar, sizeof ar / sizeof *ar, sizeof *ar, comp);
        for( unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof ar / sizeof *ar; i++ ) {
                printf(" %s: %d\n", ar[i].name, ar[i].Win);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, `int comp()` is all I need to write to change the order of the array of structures? and just print it in `main` right? Also, when I tested this code it prints out starting with 3, 7 and 5. Isn't it supposed to be 7, 5 and 3 like descending

Comment: `comp` is the function you use to indicate the ordering.  That code should print the values in the order 7,5,3, and if it's not doing that then you'll need to do some debugging.  (which is to say, it works for me).

Comment: @WilliamPursell Your comp function is wrong, it should be: ```int
comp(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
        const struct create *const *a = va;
        const struct create *const *b = vb;
        return ( (*a)->Win < (*b)->Win ) - ( (*b)->Win < (*a)->Win );
}
```

Comment: @isrnick Ah, thanks!  Yes, that explains why the sorting is inconsistent.

Comment: The main problem remains, in the function `va` and `vb` store a pointer to another pointer, so the type of `a` and `b` are wrong, they should be pointers to pointer of `const struct create`.

Comment: @ismick No.  In comp, va is a pointer to a struct create, not a pointer to pointer.  The main problem was that the comp function was only returning 1 or 0, so was incorrectly reporting that two unequal structs were equal.

Comment: Nevermind, I'd failed to see that you had also changed `ar` from an array of pointers into a normal array in the `main` function.

Answer (score -1):

Oh man!!! you don't specify anything in a precise way.... You show almost no code, no complete example, no working code.  Please, read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get on how to post in StackOverflow.  I'll assume you are using `qsort()` to sort the array in ascending order, with some function called `comparator1()`, and assume that the function is defined as:

```
int comparator1(void *a, void *b);
```

to compare structs in order to sort in ascending order.  Just write this another function:

```
int comparator2(void *a, void *b) 
{
    return -comparator1(a, b);
}
```

and pass this second comparator function to the call to `qsort()`.  You'll get the array sorted in the opposite order than before.  This way, you can control the order to be ascending or descending by just selecting one function or the other.  :)